# i am creating login api and hashed password using bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a register login logout system. at time of registration i am taking email and password
and storing hashed password. now when logging in i want to compare password entered to hashed password. so basically I want to know how can I compare and check plain password with hashed passwords

Comment: Generally, you would hash the password received in the same way you did the one you stored, and then compare the hashes.

Comment: hash is string generated randomly so for same password It will generate different hash string  @David784

Comment: No, it's not random. It depends on the input.

Comment: Reading the [OWASP Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) might clear things up a bit, regarding what hashing is and other best practices like salting etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076638/compare-passwords-bcryptjs) but am not able to mark it as such.

This should work, taken from the [bcryptJS docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076638/compare-passwords-bcryptjs).

**Sync**

```js
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
```

**Promise**

```js
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash).then(function(result) {
    // result == true
});
```