# Password Decryption

Tags: node.js, authentication, hash, passport.js

I want to decrypt the password and then compare!!
I am using bcrypt to hash the password but when i am trying to convert the hash password into password for comparison on signin it is showing Invalid username and password

please help me to do this

```
//Authentication Using Passport
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    function (req, email, password, done) {
      //Find a User and establish the identity
      User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user || user.password != password) {
            console.log("Invalid Username and Password");
            return req.res.redirect("/users/sign-in");
          }
          //Return the User if both the above condition failed
          return done(null, user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error in Finding the User ---> Passport");
          return done(err);
        });
    }
  )
);
```

Please write the code so that i can decrypt the password.

i am trying to write compare method from bycrypt but not able to solve

Comment: You don't decrypt a hash (you cannot un-hash a potato). Bcrypt has a compare method that hashes the input and compares it to the stored hash.

Comment: You can use `compare` [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077486/20250421).