Bcrypt compare sync returning incorrect output
I have the following express middleware:
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!process.env.UNIVERSAL_FS_PASSWORD) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        error: "An environment variable UNIVERSAL_FS_PASSWORD is required to protect your files",
      });
    }

    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        error: "An Authorization header is required",
      });
    }

    const token = (req.headers.authorization as string).replace(/^Bearer\s/, "");
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(token, 10);
    if (!bcrypt.compareSync (process.env.UNIVERSAL_FS_PASSWORD, hash)) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        error: "Unauthorized request",
      });
    }

    next();
  });

It is responsible for checking that the password is correct. However, when the middleware is triggered I always get a 401 status code returned. I have checked that all values are corrected and they are.
Here is an existing SO answer that I'm trying to follow but is not working https://stackoverflow.com/a/56041497/19019306

Which 401 message did you get?

The endpoint is sending a 401. "Unathorized request"

Hmm, I think you should not hash the token again, maybe it is already hashed when you generate it. So,  just compare by bcrypt.compareSync(process.env.UNIVERSAL_FS_PASSWORD, token)
